# incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int. I don't know why i'm getting this error message

Tags: java, casting, int, double

```
    private void buildingComposotion () 

{
    for (int i=1; i<=randomInteger(3,6); i++)
    {
        int numberOfStories = 2;
        buildingFrame(numberOfStories);
        buildingWindows(numberOfStories);
    }
}
private int randomInteger(int min, int max) 
{
    min = (int) Math.ceil(min);
    max = (int) Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min));
}
```

The error, "incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int." is on line 15.

Comment: There is no need for you to call `Math.ceil(min)` or `Math.floor(max)`. Those values are already integers. You also need to add `min` to the returned value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Math.floor` returns a `double`, not an `int`. Modify your `randomInteger` method:

```
private int randomInteger(int min, int max) 
{
    min = (int) Math.ceil(min);
    max = (int) Math.floor(max);
    return (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min));
}
```

Alternatively, use `nextInt` from the `Random` class

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the very quick response! This is my first time using stack over flow and i never had expected such a quick reply.

Cheers!